# how to write to specific worksheet in phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Be apprised that we are to trying export data to a particular worksheet of a workbook. For example, i'm trying to write "html" string to "Sheet - 2" in workbook_1.xls file.  Based on the documentation and other related queries, i could not find as how we can achieve this.  By default the data gets exported to the first sheet of the workbook.

This is the code i have tried until now.

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("filename.html");
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('file'.xlsx');
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

You must select your spreadsheet. You can do it by name or number

```
// Get the second sheet in the workbook
// Note that sheets are indexed from 0
$spreadsheet->getSheet(1);

// Retrieve the worksheet called 'Worksheet 1'
$spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1');
```

More see documentation [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/#worksheets).